# FATAL EXCEPTION : main (Contacts List)

Tags: android

I'm trying to show the contacts in a `list`. No matter what I do, it doesn't work.

Can someone help me with this?

P.S I'm new here. So tell me if I'm doing anything wrong.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{


ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<String>();

ListView list;

Cursor phones;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);



    phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    while(phones.moveToNext())
    {
        String contactName = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
        name.add(contactName);
    }
    phones.close();

    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, name);

    list.setAdapter(adapter);

}
}
```

Comment: Add a exception stacktrace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have not asked runtime permissions for getting Phone Contacts. From Android M and above you need to ask permission to read phone contacts at runtime.

Check this link on how to request runtime permissions- https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Also you can use google library - https://github.com/googlesamples/easypermissions to request permissions.

Comment: I didn't check the Phone option in the app's permissions. Thank you so much for the help. Cheers!